# Persistent volume error when installing Prometheus using Helm

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks

I'm trying to install Prometheus to my EKS cluster, using the default prometheus helm chart located at https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus. It deploys successfully, but in the Kubernetes Dashboard the AlertManager and Server deployments say:

> pod has unbound PersistentVolumeClaims (repeated 3 times)

I've tried tinkering with the `values.yaml` file to no avail.

I know this isn't much to go on, but I'm not really sure what else I can look up when it comes to logging.

Here's the output from running `helm install stable/prometheus --name prometheus --namespace prometheus`

```
root@fd9c3cc3f356:~/charts# helm install stable/prometheus --name prometheus --namespace prometheus
NAME:   prometheus
LAST DEPLOYED: Wed Jun 20 14:55:41 2018
NAMESPACE: prometheus
STATUS: DEPLOYED

RESOURCES:
==> v1beta1/ClusterRole
NAME                           AGE
prometheus-kube-state-metrics  1s
prometheus-server              1s

==> v1/ServiceAccount
NAME                           SECRETS  AGE
prometheus-alertmanager        1        1s
prometheus-kube-state-metrics  1        1s
prometheus-node-exporter       1        1s
prometheus-pushgateway         1        1s
prometheus-server              1        1s

==> v1/PersistentVolumeClaim
NAME                     STATUS   VOLUME  CAPACITY  ACCESS MODES  STORAGECLASS  AGE
prometheus-alertmanager  Pending  1s
prometheus-server        Pending  1s

==> v1beta1/ClusterRoleBinding
NAME                           AGE
prometheus-kube-state-metrics  1s
prometheus-server              1s

==> v1/Service
NAME                           TYPE       CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP  PORT(S)   AGE
prometheus-alertmanager        ClusterIP  10.100.3.32     <none>       80/TCP    1s
prometheus-kube-state-metrics  ClusterIP  None            <none>       80/TCP    1s
prometheus-node-exporter       ClusterIP  None            <none>       9100/TCP  1s
prometheus-pushgateway         ClusterIP  10.100.243.103  <none>       9091/TCP  1s
prometheus-server              ClusterIP  10.100.144.15   <none>       80/TCP    1s

==> v1beta1/DaemonSet
NAME                      DESIRED  CURRENT  READY  UP-TO-DATE  AVAILABLE  NODE SELECTOR  AGE
prometheus-node-exporter  3        3        2      3           2          <none>         1s

==> v1beta1/Deployment
NAME                           DESIRED  CURRENT  UP-TO-DATE  AVAILABLE  AGE
prometheus-alertmanager        1        1        1           0          1s
prometheus-kube-state-metrics  1        1        1           0          1s
prometheus-pushgateway         1        1        1           0          1s
prometheus-server              1        1        1           0          1s

==> v1/Pod(related)
NAME                                            READY  STATUS             RESTARTS  AGE
prometheus-node-exporter-dklx8                  0/1    ContainerCreating  0         1s
prometheus-node-exporter-hphmn                  1/1    Running            0         1s
prometheus-node-exporter-zxcnn                  1/1    Running            0         1s
prometheus-alertmanager-6df98765f4-l9vq2        0/2    Pending            0         1s
prometheus-kube-state-metrics-6584885ccf-8md7c  0/1    ContainerCreating  0         1s
prometheus-pushgateway-5495f55cdf-brxvr         0/1    ContainerCreating  0         1s
prometheus-server-5959898967-fdztb              0/2    Pending            0         1s

==> v1/ConfigMap
NAME                     DATA  AGE
prometheus-alertmanager  1     1s
prometheus-server        3     1s


NOTES:
The Prometheus server can be accessed via port 80 on the following DNS name from within your cluster:
prometheus-server.prometheus.svc.cluster.local


Get the Prometheus server URL by running these commands in the same shell:
  export POD_NAME=$(kubectl get pods --namespace prometheus -l "app=prometheus,component=server" -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}")
  kubectl --namespace prometheus port-forward $POD_NAME 9090


The Prometheus alertmanager can be accessed via port 80 on the following DNS name from within your cluster:
prometheus-alertmanager.prometheus.svc.cluster.local


Get the Alertmanager URL by running these commands in the same shell:
  export POD_NAME=$(kubectl get pods --namespace prometheus -l "app=prometheus,component=alertmanager" -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}")
  kubectl --namespace prometheus port-forward $POD_NAME 9093


The Prometheus PushGateway can be accessed via port 9091 on the following DNS name from within your cluster:
prometheus-pushgateway.prometheus.svc.cluster.local


Get the PushGateway URL by running these commands in the same shell:
  export POD_NAME=$(kubectl get pods --namespace prometheus -l "app=prometheus,component=pushgateway" -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}")
  kubectl --namespace prometheus port-forward $POD_NAME 9091

For more information on running Prometheus, visit:
https://prometheus.io/
```

Comment: what is the output of `kubectl describe pvc prometheus-alertmanager` for example ?

Comment: Please refer to this answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75392879/issues-setting-up-prometheus-on-eks-pods-in-pending-state-seems-to-be-depende/77758639#77758639

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out, EKS clusters are not created with any persistent storage enabled:

> Amazon EKS clusters are not created with any storage classes. You must
>   define storage classes for your cluster to use and you should define a
>   default storage class for your persistent volume claims.

[This guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/storage-classes.html) explains how to add a kubernetes StorageClass for EKS

After adding the StorageClass as instructed, deleting my prometheus deployment using `helm delete prometheus --purge` and re-creating the deployment, all of my pods are now fully functional.